# Printing count of each element in a list

Tags: python

If i have a list containing:

```
aList = [1,5,2,3,3]
```

and i want to count the number of times each element occur in the list having such output:

```
1 occur 1 time
5 occur 1 time
2 occur 1 time
3 occur 2 times
```

here's what I've tried:

```
aList = [1,5,2,3,3]
i = 0
n = len(aList)
count = 0

while i<n:
    if aList[i] == aList[i+1]:
          count +=1
    else:
         count = 1
         i+=1
print(aList[i] + str(count))
```

I'm sure it's something like this, but it's not quite right. Understanding that all i want is printing how many times each element occur in the list but when i code it everything seemed complicated. Any help is much appreciated.

I know about dictionaries but I'm not allowed to use dictionaries.

Comment: Your code only counts consecutive entries.

Answer (score 1):

Not allowing to use dictionaries seems like an arbitrary restriction and means you will have to make some other compromise (inefficiency) or assumptions around the data.

[`collections.Counter()`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/collections.html?highlight=counter#collections.Counter) is designed to solve these problems but looks like it is off limits.

Assuming you don't know what data is in the list then using a `set` allows you to know the unique items in the `list`, which you can individually count, e.g.:

```
In []:
for e in set(aList):
    c = aList.count(e)
    print("{} occurs {} time{}".format(e, c, 's' if c > 1 else ''))

Out[]:
1 occurs 1 time
2 occurs 1 time
3 occurs 2 times
5 occurs 1 time
```

But this is relatively inefficient because it counts over the list multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

My solution assumes that the list is a list of positive integers, and with a value not too high (that's equivalent to a dictionary, but with hash == value)

If that's ok, then create a table, initialized with 0, and count using the values as table indexes:

```
aList = [1,5,2,3,3]

table = [0]*(max(aList)+1)

for i in aList:
    table[i] += 1

for i,v in enumerate(table):
    if v:
        print("{} appears {} time(s)".format(i,v))
```

result:

```
1 appears 1 time(s)
2 appears 1 time(s)
3 appears 2 time(s)
5 appears 1 time(s)
```